# Where can I find this Discipline that allows a Vampire to disbelieve in sunlight, stakes, etc. so strongly that it can ignore them?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, content-identification

I had a character around 2001 that I was working on for a game that fell apart, and while reading through some book I came upon a very high-power ability that allowed a Vampire to disbelieve in something so strongly that it didn't exist for it any more. This could be anything, including doors, which would allow for entry into any room, or blood, which would be less than bright.

I have not been able to find this particular Discipline since, and I would love it if someone can tell me what it is and which sourcebook it's in.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a Dementation Advanced Power for 8 dots called Deny. It's from Clanbook Malkavaian (Revised Edition), pg. 64. (Info courtesy of the [World of Darkness Wiki](http://wiki.white-wolf.com/worldofdarkness/index.php?title=Dementation).) It would definitely work against stakes, but doesn't extend to sunlight.

> The Malkavian using Deny is able to focus away from a certain object so completely that the object ceases to exist in the Malkavian's perception... The Malkavian may step through a door that he "doesn't see" as if it were an archway; a sword that he refuses to acknowledge will fail to cut him, passing right through his body...This power cannot be used to "deny" the existence of living creatures, undead or spirits; it works only on inanimate objects.
>
> The aura of "noninterference" doesn't extend further than anything the Malkavian is holding...The Malkavian cannot help other vampires or living beings to tune out the ignored object, even if touching them; the power only benefits the Malkavian and his personal effects...

(Thanks to Flamma for the quotes!)

Comment: The quoted text doesn't rule out an immunity to sunlight... the Sun is not any sort of creature, it is an inanimate object, so one could argue that if the Sun ceases to exist for that vampire, then they're protected from sunlight. Unless there was some explicit clause relating to sunlight?